# my function doesn't return some letters even though included in utf-8 (vscode, php)

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, utf

It's supposed to spit out each letter of a string, if it's in one of the objects keys, but those odd characters æø etc. doesn't show at all and I get results like: ltkai. instead of: lætkaiø.

I'm using vscode and php (installed with scoop).

- I've attempted both UTF-8 and UTF-8 with BOM encoding in vscode.
- I already use meta charset="utf-8".
- I've tried with charset="" header().
- I've used mbstring extension to detect if it's utf-8 or not, and it always register as utf and shows the odd letters with loops and as a whole string,
  but if it's in my if stmt,
  it just doesn't register as utf,
  and utf_encode doesn't work (it's like it registers them as utf already, encodes them then, and gives odder letters back).
- I've also used property_exists() outside my function, and it works there, but still not inside.
- I've tried utf_encode, but also does not work.

  ```
  $name = 'lætkaiø';
  $vocals = (object) ['æ' => 4, 'i' => 3, 'ø' => 3, 'a' => 4];
  $konsonants = (object) ['t' => 5, 'l' => 6, 'k' => 3];

  function letters($name, $konsonants, $vocals) {
   $letterarr = str_split($name);

   foreach($letterarr as $letter){

   if (property_exists($konsonants, $letter)){
       echo($letter);
   }
   if (property_exists($vocals, $letter)){
       echo($letter);
   }

   }
  }
  ```

If anybody has any ideas why this is happening or how to solve it?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_split` operates on bytes, and characters such as `æ` take up more than 1 byte in UTF-8.

So if you `str_split` these characters, they basically get 'split in two' into an invalid character. Just run `count()` on `$letterarr` to see that there are 9 items in the array, instead of the expected 7.

The solution is to use PHP's string functions that are UTF-8 aware. Simply changing `str_split` into `mb_str_split` will fix your code sample.